# Wistia Javascript API - set video foam true and hide social buttons

Tags: javascript

Here is my code,

```
<div id="wistia_bqur1fvyag" class="wistia_embed" style="width:420px;height:234px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
<script>
  wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("bqur1fvyag", {
    plugin: {
      "socialbar-v1": {
        buttons: "",
      videoFoam: true
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

When i run this code, it shows black bar on left and right side.

I put `videoFoam: true` but, it didn't work.

Can anyone help me to remove black bar, still am i right? or can i use different api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I did it via the embed code directly, from the page linked below, using the two parameters to disable the social bar and enable videoFoam.

http://wistia.com/doc/iframe-embed-options

```
?videoFoam=true&plugin%5Bsocialbar-v1%5D%5Bon%5D=false
```

For what you have above, videoFoam is not part of the plugin but a standard parameter, so I'd try the following:

```js
wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("bqur1fvyag", {
    videoFoam: true,
    plugin: {
      "socialbar-v1": {
        on: false
      }
    }
});
```